# Is it possible to fetch the number of items with a certain property against the property from a CSVLayer in ArcGIS Javascript API?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Is it possible to fetch the number of items with a certain property against the property from a CSVLayer in ArcGIS Javascript API?

This is the [csv file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/arnofiva/8d4dffa956613fd0e0f3f26763419d1d/raw/7615737a46097836608fee317ba4941ffcfbe0ca/example.csv).

My intent is to

- **Category 0** - 1
- **Category 1** - 0
- **Category 2** - 1
- **Category 3** - 0

If we are showing Legends from the "Category" property and all the documents are in the view.

Also is it possible to filter the items based on the same property?

Also is it possible to show the details in a Pie Chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [client side queries](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-support-Query.html) to retrieve information about the visible data. Using the [CSVLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-CSVLayer.html) and [SceneView](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-SceneView.html) in the Codepen, the following code counts the number of features where `Category = 0` or `Category = 2`:

```
view
  .whenLayerView(csvLayer)
  .then(function(csvLayerView) {

    // Create query
    var query = csvLayerView.createQuery();
    query.outStatistics = [{
      onStatisticField: "CASE WHEN Category = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END",
      outStatisticFieldName: "Category0Sum",
      statisticType: "sum"
    }, {
      onStatisticField: "CASE WHEN Category = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END",
      outStatisticFieldName: "Category2Sum",
      statisticType: "sum"
    }];
    return csvLayerView.queryFeatures(query);
  })
  .then(function(response) {

    // Print query results
    console.log("Query results", response.features[0].attributes);
  }).catch(console.error);
```

The following Codepen runs this code whenever the view changes and prints a new line of results to the console: https://codepen.io/arnofiva/pen/b835cc7b626965332e802fd3385056e9

To see other query options or how to show the results as pie chart, checkout the following resources:

- API documentation for [Query](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-support-Query.html)
- [Query statistics by geometry](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-scenelayerview-query-stats/index.html) (uses pie charts)
- [Client-side filtering](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-layers-CSVLayerView.html#filter) of displayed features

Comment: Is it possible to filter out components and display only items from the CSVLayer with a certain property?

Comment: I've updated to answer with a link to client-side filtering, they essentially accept the same parameters as queries

Comment: Is it possible in ArcGIS to draw a polyline or polygon programmatically if I provide the required coordinates for the geometry. Life for a polyline I would be providing two endpoints for the line.

Comment: It is :) can you post this as a new question? I'll be happy to provide the details in an answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57389897/is-it-possible-in-arcgis-to-draw-a-polyline-or-polygon-programmatically

I have asked it as another question here.