# Is it possible in ArcGIS to draw a polyline or polygon programmatically?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Is it possible in ArcGIS to draw a polyline or polygon programmatically if I provide the required coordinates for the geometry? Like for a polyline, I would be providing two endpoints for the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible in both 2D/3D. The simplest way is adding a [`Graphic`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-Graphic.html) containing the [`Polyline`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-Polyline.html) (or any other geometry) to the view's graphics:

```
// Coordinates of Zurich, Switzerland
var pointA = [8.5107858, 47.3922425];

// Coordinates of Kochi, India
var pointB = [76.3333005, 10.0023473];

var polyline = new Graphic({
  geometry: {
    type: "polyline",
    spatialReference: { wkid: 4326 },
    paths: [[pointA, pointB]]
  },
  symbol: {
    type: "simple-line",
    color: "orange",
    width: 4
  }
});
view.graphics.add(polyline);
```

The following CodePen draws the above polyline on a 3D globe: https://codepen.io/arnofiva/pen/7ae74bb9798a01ada6d60f3d1ee5612b

[image: 3D globe with polyline]

See the following resources for more information:

- [Intro into Graphics](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/intro-graphics/index.html)
- [Add Graphics to a SceneView](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/graphics-basic-3d/index.html)
- [Sketch in 3D](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sketch-3d/index.html)

Comment: what about Polygon?

Comment: Please have a look at the add graphics sample mentioned in the answer: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/graphics-basic-3d/index.html